# Making a batch file in C# then executing it

Tags: c#, command-line, batch-file

I'm a hobby C# programmer and I'm making an interface for a CLI tool called setMACE. This is a snippet of the code that I'm using:

```
if (!File.Exists(batpath))
{
    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(batpath))
    {
        fs.Close();
    }

    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(batpath))
    {
        int outfile = r.Next(5);
        sw.WriteLine("cd " + Application.StartupPath);
        sw.WriteLine(exe + " " + "\"" + ofd.FileName + "\"" + " -d " + " >>logfile.txt");
    }
    Process proc = Process.Start(batpath);
```

And this will make the following .BAT:

```
cd C:\Users\Steve Jobs\Pictures\SetMACE_v1006
setMACE_x64.exe "C:\Users\Steve Jobs\Documents\avast.cap" -d  >>logfile.txt
```

This works when I execute this .BAT in the CMD but when I let the app run it, it spawns a new window with the program and ignores the `>output.txt`

I'm sorry if this is a no-brainer, but I can't find anything on it online.

Comment: Any reason you want to use a batch file rather than just executing the command directly?

Comment: Hey, yeah I wanted to try this out. Plus I had troubles with arguments and the >output.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're spawning a second instance of cmd, via start, which may not be starting in the same directory to which you're cd'ing

Why does your batch file have "start cmd", why don't you just run setMACE_x64.exe directly?

I.e. your batch file would then be:

```
cd C:\Users\Steve Jobs\Pictures\SetMACE_v1006
setMACE_x64.exe "C:\Users\Steve Jobs\Documents\avast.cap" -d  >>logfile.txt
```

Comment: Woops, yeah I tried that to prevent it from opening another cmd, but it didn't work. I've tried start /B start and just the executable, all the same. But thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string str = @"/c cd C:\Users\Steve Jobs\Pictures\SetMACE_v1006";
String str2 = @"setMACE_x64.exe ""C:\Users\Steve Jobs\Documents\avast.cap"" -d  >>logfile.txt"
Process.Start("cmd.exe", str);
Process.Start("cmd.exe", str2);
```

I hope this will help